# Magento Custom Messaging

Tags: magento

We have an attribute code called `web_availability` to message different forms of product availability to the customer - Example: Availability "80" should message "In Store Only" on a search result and/or a product detail page. Each of the availability values that we set up are automatically assigned an option value in magento as follows:

`<input type="text" class="input-text required-option" value="80" name="option[value][532][0]">`

I declared the variables as:

```
    <?php
$_shipping_messaging = $_product->getShippingMessaging(); //looks for a value of "0" or "1" to assign either Free Shipping, or Plus Shipping Messaging
$_shipping_price = $_product->getShippingPrice(); //if product is plus shipping this messages the approximate shipping price on the product

$web_avail_options = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('web_availability')) {
foreach ($web_avail_options as $web_avail_option) {
    if ($web_avail_option['value'] == $_product->getData('web_availability')) {
        $web_availability = $web_avail_option['label'];
        }
  }
  ?>
```

Placed the following into magento's price.phtml:

```
    <?php
  if ($shipping_messaging == 0) {
      echo '+ $' . number_format($_shipping_price, 2) . " Shipping"; // displays "+ $x.xx Shipping" on the product page
  } elseif ($_shipping_messaging == 1) {
      echo "Free Shipping"; // displays "Free Shipping" on the product page
  }
  else ($web_avail_option == '70' || '80' || '90'); {
      echo "In Store Only";
  }

  ?>
```

The shipping messaging ("Free Shipping", or "+ $4.80 Shipping) appear as I would expect them to, however it ALWAYS displays the "In Store Only" message regardless of the product's avilability. I have tried every conceivable combination of  `==`, `<`, `>`, as well as using different parts of the initial variable I declared at the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please notice your code, especially the else statement.

`else ($web_avail_option == '70' || '80' || '90'); {
      echo "In Store Only";
}`

The else statement is formatted wrong, please notice below code. Your else statement is checking if the web avail option is 70 but you're not using an `elseif` and after the OR operator you're checking 80. Well.. 80 is always true.

A sulution: You may want to save the correct state in an array (example: `$correct_status = array(70,80,90);`. If these code are saved in an array, you can use below else statement.

`elseif(in_array($web_avail_option, $correct_status)) { echo "In store only"; }`